# How do I put a picture from my computer to my html website?

Tags: html, image, github

How do I put a picture from my computer to my html website?
I have a picture on my computer that is not on the internet and I want to put it in my html website hosted in GitHub.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.  If it's just a picture on just a static html page, do a Google search for the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Can I host an image a github website (exampleusername.github.io) like "exaple.github.io/img/example.jpeg"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a local image directly onto your website, but you can upload it to a website such as https://ibb.co and include the HTML in *your* website.

Comment: That is really cool but can I have it be "exaple.github.io/img/example.jpeg"?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by uploading the image from your computer as a file on your github repository. Then you would include it in your html like <img src="imagename.jpeg">